# Instantiate a class based on the data coming from a form

Tags: php, jquery, class, oop

I want to instantiate a specific class when my php script gets data from input field with name="files[]"

for example someone upload a file using one of the input field on my html form, jquery sends data to php as json and in php I put up different classes and each class gets instantiate based on the name attribute's value of the input field.

This is what I am trying to do

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
if (!empty($_REQUEST) && empty($_REQUEST['files[]']) && empty($_REQUEST['files2[]'])) {
$upload_handler1 = new UploadHandler();
}
else { 
    if ($_REQUEST['files']) {
    $custom_upload_handlerone = new customUploadHandlertwo();
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['files2']) {
    $custom_upload_handlertwo = new customUploadHandlerone();
    }
}
```

If someone don't use that specified input field to send data, the simple class UploadHandler should instantiate and once I send an input field let's say with name="file2[]" attribute. The script stop the UploadHandler instantiation and instantiate class customUploadHandlertwo

Comment: Can you explain the problem more? This isn't clear: "class UploadHandler should instantiate till I send specified input field data to my php script."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a relation with the name attribute of the field and the php class. If so instantiation of such class is simple as follows

```
...
else { 
    if ($_REQUEST['files']) {
    $className = $_REQUEST['files'];
    $custom_upload_handlerone = new $className();
    }
    if ($_REQUEST['files2']) {
    $className = $_REQUEST['files2'];
    $custom_upload_handlertwo = new $className();
    }
}
...
```